# How to Deploy MEAN STACK application in private VPS server

Tags: mean-stack

I made a mean stack application and its running fine in localhost, I want to deploy my application on my VPS server but I don't know how to deploy and what is the procedure, please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well i do it with the MEVN stack like this:

I develop it on my localhost, then i create an folder on my vps and load everything up on my VPS on that folder, for exmaple with Filezilla.

Then i use Putty to create a SSH connection to my server, i log in and move to my folder i create with `cd my-folder`
After that you start your application with `node your-application`

Ofcorse you need to have Node.js installed and MongoDB installed on your vps